# How to install native assembler for Mac OSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, assembly

I am interested to know how can I install native assemblar (I think also known as AS) on Mac OSX Lion. Someone suggested that I can use the Xcode to do it but I didn't see any options.Terminal windows is not able to recognize AS as command right now. Can someone provide more insight on this ? I am new to Mac/Unix environment so please provide help accordingly.

Comment: If you don't want to use the command line, you can do it directly in Xcode. Just create a command-line tool with the type set to "C" (so that it doesn't link in any frameworks), then delete the C file and add assembly files with a `.s` extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Xcode installed, then you have `as`.
There is no option to install specific packages from the Xcode installer.

`as` should be in `/usr/bin/`:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/as
```

If not, you probably have a problem with your Xcode installation.

Otherwise, also check your `PATH` environment variable, to ensure `/usr/bin/` is in the list.

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: It's been a while since I used the installer, but I thought there was a "Unix development" option which you had to check in order for the compilers to be placed in `/usr/bin`, and without it you only get a copy in `<Xcode folder>/usr/bin` (and in the SDKs as necessary).

Comment: In the (very) old versions of Xcode, yep... But no more in today's versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed Xcode 4.3, it doesn't install the command line tools anymore. To get them, you have to launch Xcode, go to Xcode > Preferences... > Downloads tab, then click the 'Download' button for 'Command Line Tools'. You'll need to sign in with an Apple Developer ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 4.6 with Command Line Utilities installed
`export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH`
as will execute along with the other command line utilities.